# search box for all the pages after Django pagination of table

Tags: javascript, django, pagination

I have developed a web app using Django.

I have created a table pagination.
how could I create a search input for all the data in all the pages of table?

view.py

```
def Browse_and_adopt(request):
    Title_list = Title.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(Title_list, 10)
    try:
        Titles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        Titles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        Titles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)



    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, 'bms/inbox/Browse_and_adopt.html', {'Titles': Titles, 'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Browse_and_adopt.html

```
          <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                % for book in page_obj %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
                                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Now only the first page shows, how to create a search bar for all the data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

The view does not know whick object you are looking for.

There is two ways to do so.

In the frontend end where you write a JS callback event listener that filter all the supplied table data. " not optimal ''

Or you can create a custom view that recieve the object pk via post request and return the filtered result e.g url :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<int:pk>/', updateViewSet.as_view()),
]
```